# Apache rewrite rule is getting ignored while other functions are working properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-14.04

I have LAMP server running on Ubuntu 14.04, and everything seems to be configured fine. The Only problem that am having is that, the rewrite rule is somehow getting ignored without issuing any error. The page reloads again as usual after modifying the **.htaccess** file. What I am trying to do, is to route all traffic to index.php using the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Other rules are functioning properly, eg. if I add `deny from all` and reload the page,I immediately get en error. All files and folders are located in the `/var/www/` root directory. I don't know what am missing here, I spent hours debugging this issue without a solution :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to redirect all traffic to index.php by pointing the document root to index.php:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

thanks @Chris for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The `.` will only match a single character. Try using `.*` to match anything.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: @Angie With regards to the deleted comment, `RewriteRule` does not match substrings, only the full string. It effectively has an implicit `^` and `$` around it. Did this help you? If so would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: hi Chris, it doesn't work. The pages are refreshing as usual !! really strange.

Comment: @Angie Could you check `mod_rewrite` is enabled by running `apache2ctl -M` and check what your `AllowOverride` directive in the `<Directory /var/www/html>` block of your Apache config says. It needs to either contain `FileInfo` or `All`.

Comment: I have check that, it seems to be configure wright: `<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>`

Comment: @Angie I'm glad you found a solution. Just FYI, that `AllowOverride` directive is not correct. If you change it to `AllowOverride All` and then restart Apache you will probably find your `.htaccess` method works.

Comment: oh, I pasted in the wrong code, Its set to AllowOverride All.

Comment: @Angie Okay then. I'm not sure what the problem is, but it's great you've found another solution.